# Symfony HTTP response doesn't contain the specified body

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, httpresponse

I'm using the following javascript code to execute an HTTP request:

```
function ready(path) {
    fetch(path, {method : 'put'})
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

This request triggers the following function on my server:

```
/**
 * @Route("/some/route/{playerName}", name="ready")
 * @param $playerName string
 */
public function toggleReady($playerName) {
    $this->someService->readyUp($playerName);

    $response = new Response(
        'TOGGLE SUCCESS!',
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        array('content-type' => 'text/html'));
    $response->send();
}
```

On the client side, `then` is being called and prints a response in the console. That response holds the correct status code, but the body is empty with `bodyUsed` being `false`. How can I properly send my desired content/body to the frontend?

Comment: Did you try using the 'body' attribute alongside the 'method' attribute?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Also try this:
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

Comment: As far as I understand the `body` attribute for `fetch` sets the body of the request and has no influence on what response I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do this:

```
fetch(path, {method : 'put'})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Here's the content of the body
    console.log(data)
});
```

"Turns out, what we requested is hidden in body as a readable stream. We need to call an appropriate method to convert this readable stream into data we can consume.

In case of working with GitHub, we know the response is JSON. We can call response.json to convert the data.

There are other methods to deal with different types of response. If you're requesting an XML file, then you should call response.text. If you're requesting an image, you call response.blob."

See https://css-tricks.com/using-fetch/

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Content-Type` header is `text/html`, you should parse the response body as text using the `.text()` method which returns a promise:

```
fetch(path, { method: 'put' })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Furthermore, a `text/plain` would be more accurate than `text/html`